# Rollbacking changes made by lambda in CloudFormation

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-cloudformation

Is there any way to rollback all the changes made by an AWS Lambda by using the SDK? E.g. the lambda created and launched by a CloudFormation template creates a bucket via the AWS SDK. In case something fails it would be great to have a 'stack rollback' for the same stack that deployed the lambda as well (and all the resources created by the lambda reverted as well).

Or alternatively: how can I 'remember' from my lambda which resources were created so that I can rollback them and delete them when the lambda is called afterwards with a 'Delete' event?

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you mean custom resources, as that's the only way you can run scripts in cloudformation.

Custom resources have a property called `pysicalReourceId`. You can use it after your create event to provide info over the resource you've created. When updating or deleting the resource, the id is provided to the lambda event so you can use it. A guide can also be found here: https://advancedweb.hu/how-to-use-the-physicalresourceid-for-cloudformation-custom-resources/

If for some reason it's not possible to use the resource ID I'd use tagging. When creating, tag your resources and when deleting, fetch the resources based on their tag and delete them.